# No swap after moving/resizing partitions

Tags: partitioning, swap

I recently did a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04 andpurposly got rid of my windows partition and my original swap partition in the process. Now my system won't see any swap space. My partition table is set up like this:

- `/dev/sda2 ext4` 459.24GB (main ubuntu partition)
- `/dev/sda1 linux-swap` 6.52GB (unrecognized swap space)

I even ran the `free` command in the terminal and it wouldn't see anything:

```bash
    _zach@Skynet:~$ free

                 total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
    Mem:       4048624    1782908    2265716          0      42332     709264
    -/+ buffers/cache:    1031312    3017312
    Swap:            0          0          0

    zach@Skynet:~$
```

So my question is, what can I do to get my system to recognize my swap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In a terminal, run the command

   ```
   sudo blkid
   ```

   This command is used to locate/print block device attributes.
2. Then read the file `/etc/fstab` with the command `cat /etc/fstab`. You are looking for an entry denoting your swap partition, if it isn't there then

   ```
   sudo gedit /etc/fstab
   ```

   and add a line at the end of fstab to automount your swap partition. It will read as follows:

   ```
   UUID=<enter here the UUID for your /dev/sda1 device> none swap sw
   ```
3. Save the fstab file and then reboot.

Comment: Why does the UUID changes after partition resizing ?

Comment: I don't know, possibly because (being a different size) it is now effectively a 'new' partition?